# Managing conversation context in amazon lex

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

How to configure the amazon Lex chatbot to notify the chat user whenever the session timeout happens automatically?

Comment: I would like to notify the chat user that your session is expired. Please restart to start new chat. I should notify the above message automatically once the user session timeout. Is there any option to configure in the amazon lex? Please advise.

Comment: The problem is that you need to respond only when you receive a user input. So you can't / shouldn't send a notification message if the user walked away for a time or took too long to respond. You'll have to simply wait for the user to send another message, check your session timeout, then notify them that the session expired and handle their input as the start of a new session.

If you want more of an answer than that, you'll have to share some code that you tried and explain your setup more. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. Actually we have built the way you suggested. We are curious that if there is an option in lex then we could just use it.

Comment: Timeout is your requirement then you can simply control it from your frontend implementation, given that Lex works on a per request basis and context is addressed in specific cases only where a follow up would be required mostly. Coming to the timeout, you can know simply based on request and thereafter simply add rules and response that you'd want.